# Url params encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a route like this

```
/api/service/:id
```

But `id` is a string like `name.of.something`

So the the url will look like:

```
/api/service/name.of.something?other=parameters
```

The controller can't parse that request correctly because of dots.

How should I decode the `id` to pass it to the route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `constraints` option to the route that will cause it to accept periods. Note that this will break Rails' automatic format detection, so you will have to pass an explicit `?format=json` to the URL if you specifically need format selection.

```
get "api/service/:id", to: "some#endpoint", constraints: {id: /[[:alnum:]_\.-]+/i}
```

Adjust the regex to your preference.